# parsing telegram MessageMediaPoll and print it as readable text

Tags: python, telegram

Good day every one,

I'm trying to parse telegram poll data, I have the following:

```
{'_': 'MessageMediaPoll', 'poll': {'_': 'Poll', 'id': 578954245254551900254, 'question': 'Have you seen it ?! ', 'answers': [{'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Lost', 'option': [48]}, {'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Am lose', 'option': [49]}, {'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Have lost', 'option': [50]}, {'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Am losing', 'option': [51]}], 'closed': False, 'public_voters': False, 'multiple_choice': False, 'quiz': True, 'close_period': None, 'close_date': None}, 'results': {'_': 'PollResults', 'min': False, 'results': [{'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [48], 'voters': 2066, 'chosen': False, 'correct': True}, {'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [49], 'voters': 471, 'chosen': False, 'correct': False}, {'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [50], 'voters': 704, 'chosen': False, 'correct': False}, {'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [51], 'voters': 279, 'chosen': True, 'correct': False}], 'total_voters': 3520, 'recent_voters': [], 'solution': None, 'solution_entities': []}}
```

and I want to print it like this:

Q: Have you seen it ?!

A: Lost|Correct

A: Am lose|Incorrect

A: Have lost|Incorrect

A: Am losing|Incorrect

How I can achieve that in Python? and what is the type of the data? json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'_': 'MessageMediaPoll', 'poll': {'_': 'Poll', 'id': 57894245245450254, 'question': 'Have you seen it ?! ', 'answers': [{'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Lost', 'option': [48]}, {'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Am lose', 'option': [49]}, {'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Have lost', 'option': [50]}, {'_': 'PollAnswer', 'text': 'Am losing', 'option': [51]}], 'closed': False, 'public_voters': False, 'multiple_choice': False, 'quiz': True, 'close_period': None, 'close_date': None}, 'results': {'_': 'PollResults', 'min': False, 'results': [{'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [48], 'voters': 2066, 'chosen': False, 'correct': True}, {'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [49], 'voters': 471, 'chosen': False, 'correct': False}, {'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [50], 'voters': 704, 'chosen': False, 'correct': False}, {'_': 'PollAnswerVoters', 'option': [51], 'voters': 279, 'chosen': True, 'correct': False}], 'total_voters': 3520, 'recent_voters': [], 'solution': None, 'solution_entities': []}}

Questionz = data['poll']['question']
Answerz = ""
Truez = ""
fullData = ""

#print(data['poll']['question'])
for answer in data['poll']['answers']:
  #print(answer['text'], answer['option'])
  Answerz = Answerz + answer['text'] + "\n"
  #print(answer['text'])


for results in data['results']['results']:
  #print(results['correct'])
  Truez = Truez + str(results['correct']) + "\n"
  
TruezLines = Truez.split("\n")
n = 0
for line in Answerz.splitlines():
    print(line, "|||||||||" ,TruezLines[n])
    fullData = line, "|||||||||" ,TruezLines[n]
    n += 1
```

Comment: Dear responder, you are not only responding to a specific person in a specific time, but also you are responding to all the people who will possibly have the same issue in the future. We appreciate your contribution but if you want to have make a great impact. So, please consider adding as much more documentation to your answer as you can. Regards.